# MySQL HAVING with specific number within GROUP_CONCAT

Tags: mysql, having

I have a Query that works like a charm, but now I need to filter it by a value that is currently in a **`GROUP_CONCAT`** created field.  i have learned that I can use HAVING to filter but I can't find the syntax to use as *`HAVING groupconcatname LIKE '%6%'`* will find 6, 16, 26 etc .. I need to have the statement search for specific values so it can find "8" within the groupconcat containing `1,5,8,18,30,58` and not find **8 AND 18 AND 58** because i used a LIKE '%%'.

**My Query** (works right now .. but finds too many results based on a partial match of `%6%`):

```
SELECT offers.*, s.short_name AS sponsorName, s.logo AS sponsorLogo, GROUP_CONCAT( mn.title) titles, 
   GROUP_CONCAT( mo.`name`) metas, GROUP_CONCAT( om.meta_option) AS meta_ids
FROM offers 
INNER JOIN offer_metas as om ON om.offer_id = local_ld_offers.id 
INNER JOIN meta_options as mo ON om.meta_option = mo.id 
INNER JOIN meta_names as mn ON mo.category = mn.category AND mo.cat_seq = mn.seq 
LEFT JOIN sponsors AS s ON s.id=offers.sponsor 
GROUP BY offers.id 
HAVING meta_ids LIKE '%6%'
ORDER BY end_date ASC
```

I need to replace `HAVING meta_ids LIKE '%6%'` with something more akin to `WHERE '6' IN meta_ids` but when i try to replace the HAVING statement, with what seems like a reasonable attempt at a functioning **WHERE**, it ignores the fact that `meta_ids` is a valid variable/field to use in my clause and errors out.

Any recommendations?

Thanks,

Silver Tiger

**UPDATE - Solved unless there is a more elegant way**

Based on the recommendations from Thomas below I have updated the query and apparently I can search for as many individual values as I need by adding a line per option using the updated method as follows:

```
WHERE EXISTS( SELECT * FROM offer_metas AS om1 WHERE om1.meta_option = mo.id AND om1.meta_option = '23')
OR EXISTS( SELECT * FROM offer_metas AS om1 WHERE om1.meta_option = mo.id AND om1.meta_option = '16')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't clear  exactly what is being asked here (some test inputs with expected outputs would help) but it doesn't sound like you really need a Having clause. If you want to filter for values where say `om.meta_option` is "like" 8, then add a Where clause like so:

```
Where Exists    (
                Select 1
                From meta_options As om1
                Where om1.meta_option = mo.id
                    And om1.meta_option = Like '%8%'
                )
```

Of course, this return rows where there exists `8`, `80`, `18` and `181`. If you are looking for a specific value equal to `8`, then use:

```
Where Exists    (
                Select 1
                From meta_options As om1
                Where om1.meta_option = mo.id
                    And om1.meta_option = '8'
                )
```

If what you seek is a series of values, then you can do something like:

```
Where Exists    (
                Select 1
                From meta_options As om1
                Where om1.meta_option = mo.id
                    And om1.meta_option In('8','23')
                )
```

Remember that the purpose of the Having clause to apply filters *after* the grouping and the Where clause applies filters prior to the grouping. In this case, it sounds like the filtering should happen prior to the grouping and thus the Where clause should be used.

Comment: the problem is that the om.meta_option is a one to may field (hence the necessity for the use of GROUP_CONCAT).  I can not query om.meta_option directly as it would not be a relative result and not return the other joined table dat correctly. I need to search and filter/match within the group_concat to ensure proper results.

Comment: @Silvertiger - The Exists clause as I've written it accounts for the other files because the joins are filtering out meta_options rows that should be considered in addition to the Exists clause. Still, if you were worried about it, you can simply expand the Exists clause.

Comment: @Silvertiger - Keep in mind that the effect of the Having clause would be that say `8` for example exists somewhere in the group_concat result. The exists clause as I've written it is doing the same.

Comment: yes .. but your solution is searching explicitly fort he value while I can not do that with the HAVING .. since I can't say HAVING '8' if my group_concat result is (8,4,5,6,7) because the group_concat doesn't match exactly... right?

Comment: I have updated my question to include the solution. thank you very much.

Comment: @Silvertiger - Yes, there is a more elegant solution to your updated problem. I'll update my post to demonstrate

Answer (score 0):

You can change `HAVING meta_ids LIKE '%6%'` to `HAVING meta_ids LIKE '%,6,%' OR '6,%' OR '%,6' OR '6'` which should get what you're looking for.

Alternatives include things like subqueries, like the % operator are not very nice performance wise.

Comment: yeah .. but that is the same as "like '%6%'" since you are finding ",6," as well as "26," as well as ",68" etc .... that exaserbates the situation.

Comment: The extra cases make sure that they are accounted for: (6 in between other numbers) or (6 as starting) or (6 as ending) or (6 on its own)

Comment: Not sure whether you've actually attempted my solution, as it addresses all cases for possibilities of a '6' in `meta_ids`.

Comment: @Silvertiger This answer is also valid as I have just tried this. You are wrong in sayin gthat it is finding 26 and 68 as well. Take a look at this again it is not finding 26 or 68.